# Evaluate combinations in python

Tags: python, math, combinations

I'm python user and I'm evaluate combination in python.

For two integers m,n, nCm=n!/(m!*(n-m)!)

So, I defined factorial and combination function.

factorial function is working, but combination function does not working.

What is the error?

1> Factorial Function

```
def factorial(a):
    f=1
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        f=f*i
print(f)
```

2> Combination Function

```
def Combination(n,m):
    fn=factorial(n)
    fm=factorial(m)
    fnm=factorial(n-m)
    ncm=factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))
    print(ncm)
```

In factorial function, For example, factorial(4)=24 is working in python.

But, In combination function,

When I typing Combination(4,2),

```
    24
2
2
24
2
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-daae2b10838c> in <module>()
----> 1 Combination(4,2)

<ipython-input-17-76c6e425ad35> in Combination(n, m)
      3     fm=factorial(m)
      4     fnm=factorial(n-m)
----> 5     ncm=factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))
      6     print(ncm)
      7 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

What's the matter in my coding?

Comment: You aren't returning anything in your `factorial` function

Comment: what about "return" in the factorial def? :D

Comment: Are you sure the indentation in your 'factorial` code is actually as shown here? Your results imply that the final line `print(f)` is actually indented one level. That would explain the results you get for `factorial()`. Since you do not return a value, that explains the results in `Combination()`.

Comment: your function `factorial` only prints the result, but does not really `return` anything.

Comment: As @DavidG said. Also, what is the point of `fn=factorial(n)` if you still calculate `factorial(n)`  again few lines below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `printing` the output of a function, you should `return` the result.

```
def factorial(a):
    f=1
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        f=f*i
    return f

def combination(n,m):
    return = factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))

print combination(4,2)
```

One more remark: after calculating `factorial(n)`, it will be stored in your `fn` variable. You shouldn't calculate it again, but rather take that value and "recycle" it.

Comment: The remark is applicable for the code you posted as well :D

Comment: @BradSolomon - you sure? I still see `factorial(n)` calculated twice

Comment: @Adelin ah, my mistake, you are right.  Thought you were referring to print/return.

Comment: @Adelin: In my opinion it is usefull to change only the important things in a code and comment on what else could be improved. Beginners will be confused if their code is corrected in all different ways and will just copy & paste. I don't think it was necessary to update my answer, but, well...

Comment: @offeltoffel Depends on how you do it

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(a):
    f=1
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        f=f*i
    return f

def Combination(n,m):
    fn=factorial(n)
    fm=factorial(m)
    fnm=factorial(n-m)
    ncm=fn/(fm*fnm)
    print(ncm)

Combination(4,2)
```

In your code there is missing `return` statement in `factorial function`.